# Loop script to extract multiple PDFs to text files using Python PDFMiner

Tags: python, loops, pdf, pdfminer

Grateful for your help.  I found this sample script to extract a PDF to a text file:
https://gist.github.com/vinovator/c78c2cb63d62fdd9fb67

This works, and it is probably the most accurate extraction I've found.  I would like to edit it to loop through multiple PDFs and write them to multiple text files, all with the same name as the PDF they were created from.  I'm struggling to do so and keep either only writing one text file, or overwriting the PDFs I'm trying to extract from.  Anyone able just to help me with a loop that will loop through all PDFs in a single folder and extract them to individual text files of the same name as the PDF?

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
    import os
    from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
    from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
    from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
    # From PDFInterpreter import both PDFResourceManager and PDFPageInterpreter
    from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
    from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice
    # Import this to raise exception whenever text extraction from PDF is not allowed
    from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed
    from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox, LTTextLine
    from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator

    base_path = "C://some_folder"

    my_file = os.path.join(base_path + "/" + "test_pdf.pdf")
    log_file = os.path.join(base_path + "/" + "pdf_log.txt")

    password = ""
    extracted_text = ""

    # Open and read the pdf file in binary mode
    fp = open(my_file, "rb")

    # Create parser object to parse the pdf content
    parser = PDFParser(fp)

    # Store the parsed content in PDFDocument object
    document = PDFDocument(parser, password)

    # Check if document is extractable, if not abort
    if not document.is_extractable:
        raise PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed

    # Create PDFResourceManager object that stores shared resources such as fonts or images
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()

    # set parameters for analysis
    laparams = LAParams()

    # Create a PDFDevice object which translates interpreted information into desired format
    # Device needs to be connected to resource manager to store shared resources
    # device = PDFDevice(rsrcmgr)
    # Extract the decive to page aggregator to get LT object elements
    device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)

    # Create interpreter object to process page content from PDFDocument
    # Interpreter needs to be connected to resource manager for shared resources and device 
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

    # Ok now that we have everything to process a pdf document, lets process it page by page
    for page in PDFPage.create_pages(document):
         # As the interpreter processes the page stored in PDFDocument object
         interpreter.process_page(page)
         # The device renders the layout from interpreter
         layout = device.get_result()
         # Out of the many LT objects within layout, we are interested in LTTextBox and LTTextLine
         for lt_obj in layout:
             if isinstance(lt_obj, LTTextBox) or isinstance(lt_obj, LTTextLine):
                   extracted_text += lt_obj.get_text()
        
    #close the pdf file
    fp.close()

    # print (extracted_text.encode("utf-8"))
        
    with open(log_file, "wb") as my_log:
        my_log.write(extracted_text.encode("utf-8"))
    print("Done !!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following directory structure:

```
script.py
pdfs
  ├─a.pdf
  ├─b.pdf
  └─c.pdf
txts
```

Where `script.py` is your Python script, `pdfs` is a folder containing your PDF documents, and `txts` is an empty folder where the extracted text files should go.

We can use `pathlib.Path.glob` to discover the paths of all PDF documents in a given directory. We iterate over the paths, and for each path we open the corresponding PDF document, parse it, extract the text and save the text in a text document (with the same name) in the `txts` folder.

```
def main():

    from pathlib import Path

    from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
    from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
    from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
    from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
    from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice
    from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox, LTTextLine
    from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator

    for path in Path("pdfs").glob("*.pdf"):
        with path.open("rb") as file:
            parser = PDFParser(file)
            document = PDFDocument(parser, "")
            if not document.is_extractable:
                continue

            manager = PDFResourceManager()
            params = LAParams()

            device = PDFPageAggregator(manager, laparams=params)
            interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, device)

            text = ""

            for page in PDFPage.create_pages(document):
                interpreter.process_page(page)
                for obj in device.get_result():
                    if isinstance(obj, LTTextBox) or isinstance(obj, LTTextLine):
                        text += obj.get_text()
        with open("txts/{}.txt".format(path.stem), "w") as file:
            file.write(text)
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks.  Does exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

The script author specifies the input and output files at the start with two parameters: `my_file` and `log_file`

You can convert the script to a function that takes these as inputs and performs the extraction, then loop this function multiple times.

```
# import statemates as in the original script
base_path = "C://some_folder"

# Define a pair of tuples with lists of your file names
my_files = ("pdf1.pdf","pdf2.pdf")
log_files = ("log1.txt","log2.txt")

# This is called a list comprehension, it takes each of the 
# files listed above and generates the complete file path
my_files = [os.path.join(base_path,x) for x in my_files]
log_files = [os.path.join(base_path,x) for x in log_files]

# Function to extract the file
def extract(my_file,log_file):
    # code to perform the file extraction as in the original script

# loop through the file names, 
# as we have two list, use a range of indices instead of for name in my_files 
for i in range(len(my_files)):
    extract(my_files[i],log_files[i])
```

You should also check the documentation for `os.path.join` as your usage is not best practice (it may break when switching operating systems).